# Oracle SQL Developer Triggers IF

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

The question is asking me to update the Reorder to either "Y" or "N" depending on whether what the store has on hand is less then the Minimum requirement.

Here is what I have so far, but it keeps giving me error. This is my first time writing triggers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_REORDER 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF ON_HAND, MINIMUM ON PART
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.ON_HAND <= NEW.MINIMUM THEN
  SET NEW.REORDER = 'Y';
ELSE
  SET NEW.REORDER = 'N';
 END IF;
END;
```

Found a solution to my problems, `AFTER` has its limitation, so from reading this little [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) about `BEFORE` and `AFTER` triggers and this other [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_tr.htm#1007035) about triggers as well.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_REORDER 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ON_HAND, MINIMUM ON PART
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.ON_HAND < :NEW.MINIMUM THEN
  :NEW.REORDER := 'Y';
ELSE
  :NEW.REORDER := 'N';
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Is it a typo `NEW. >>>>REDORDER <<<` ?

Comment: Also, add to your question what is the error.

Comment: Also, this is your first time on here. The second time, before you post, check the tabs to make sure they are the right ones (the website attaches pretty random ones). I will fix it for you the first time.

Comment: yes it was a typo i fixed it and the errors are


Error(6,6): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


Error(6,10): PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option


Error(8,6): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


Error(8,10): PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: Do you mean `set reorder = ...`? (There is no **new** `reorder`!)

Comment: I tried `SET REORDER =  'Y';`

Comment: If this is oracle you should use `:new.` or `:old.` with the colon before the words

Comment: @JorgeCampos ya i tried that, but still no luck.

Comment: Remove this: `OF ON_HAND, MINIMUM` and try again

Comment: @JorgeCampos I found my error, there are restrictions on `AFTER...` in my second line. The `AFTER...` needed to be changed to `BEFORE...` and `=` needed to be changed to `:=`

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Great!! Add an answer of your own, that way you may help others.

Comment: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) This is where they talked about `BEFORE...` and `AFTER...` if interested.